# Accumulating lists with letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to right a code that accumulates a list.
The code I've figured out so far does that but I want to make it work with letters e.g. 
accumulate("a", "b", "c")
would come out to be a, ab, abc.

```
def accumulate(L):
    theSum = 0
    for i in L:
        theSum = theSum + i
        print(theSum)
    return theSum

accumulate([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Just declare `theSum` as an empty string: `theSum = ""`

Comment: @zwer pedantic nitpick, but that isn't a declaration - Python doesn't *have* variable declarations.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - fair point, but too late to edit... `s/declare/initialize/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @WillemVanOnsem has provided you with the method that would work, to shorten your code you can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) from the standard library:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> 
>>> for step in accumulate(['a', 'b', 'c']):
    print(step)


a
ab
abc
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to let it work with strings, you have to **initialize it with an empty string**:

```
def accumulate(*args):
    theSum = ''
    for i in args:
        theSum += i  # we can here shorten it to += (kudos to @ChristianDean)
        print(theSum)
    return theSum
```

Furthermore if you want to use an arbitrary number of arguments, you should use `*args` (or `*L`).

Now of course this will no longer work with numbers. The `theSum += i` is *here* short for `theSum = theSum + i` (since strings are immutable). Note however that this is *not* always the case: for lists there is a difference for instance.

Now it prints:

```
>>> accumulate("a", "b", "c")
a
ab
abc
'abc'
```

The last `'abc'` is not a result of a `print(..)` statement, but it is the `return` of the `accumulate` function.

Comment: Also note that `theSum = theSum + i` could be shortened to `theSum += i`.

Comment: @ChristianDean: yes. Added to the answer :).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import string

l = string.ascii_lowercase

the_list = []

letter = ""

for i in l:
    letter += i
    the_list.append(letter)
```

Even better in a function with a generator:

```
def accumulation():
     l = string.ascii_lowercase
     letter = ""
     for i in l:
        letter += i
        yield letter

the_letters = list(accumulation())
print(the_letters)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde', 'abcdef', 'abcdefg', 'abcdefgh', 'abcdefghi', 'abcdefghij', 'abcdefghijk', ...]
```